# What branch of math is this?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

In this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0505016v1.pdf what are the branch(es) of math being used? The unnumbered eq. on the top of page 3 and eq. (7) are good examples. All I've been able to figure out so far is integrating over groups is part of Random Matrix Theory. Group theory is also involved, but that goes without saying.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: quantum gauge theory?

Comment: Isn't that a branch of physics?

Comment: so you are only interested in the maths aspects of the paper not the physics?

Comment: Yes and no, I want to get a good grounding in the math before I learn the physics. I've found I learn it easier that way. I guess I'm different than most physicists in that respect.

Comment: well I noticed lie groups, lie theory is used in the paper

Comment: [Functional integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration), which is the main mathematical tool behind [Feynman's path integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation). Overall, a very powerful mix of calculus $($integrals$)$, topology $($manifolds and diffeomorphisms$)$ and graph theory.

Comment: @Lucian Do you know of any good books that cover Functional Integration?

Comment: No! I never even knew that such a thing existed until today! Try *Google Books* and *Amazon*, though.